# Subspec vendored_frameworks as another cocoapod library

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am developing a framework and my framework internally makes use of another third-party framework which is distributed via cocoaPods.

Even my framework will be consumed as a pod framework.

I know "vendored_frameworks" attribute is used in the podspec to include a third-party library, but in my case this third-party library is another cocoapods framework.

How to achieve this kind of dependency hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dependency`](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency) in your podspec to refer to another pod:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'YourFramework'
  s.version          = '42'

  // your usual podspec stuff

  s.dependency 'TheCocoaPodYouDependOn'
end
```